# How can I fix the 'QRCode' namespace error while writing a C# API to generate QR codes from text inputs?

Tags: c#, qr-code

I cannot add my logo to the QR Code. Please take a look at my code and point out my errors. Here is an example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using QRCoder;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace TodoAPI.Controllers
{
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class QRCodeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("GenerateQRCodeLogo")]
    public IActionResult GenerateQRCodeLogo(string text)
    {
        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(text, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        PngByteQRCode qrCode = new PngByteQRCode(qrCodeData);
        byte[] qrCodeBytes = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
        string logoPath = @".\Controllers\logo.jpg";
        using (Image logoImage = Image.FromFile(logoPath))
        {
            using (Bitmap logoBitmap = new Bitmap(logoImage.Width, logoImage.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(logoBitmap))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(logoImage, 0, 0);
                }
                int logoSize = 80;
                // Thay thế một phần của QR code bằng logo
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(qrCodeBytes))
                {
                    using (Bitmap qrCodeImage = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms)))
                    {
                        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(qrCodeImage))
                        {
                            graphics.DrawImage(logoBitmap, new Rectangle(qrCodeImage.Width / 2 - logoSize / 2, qrCodeImage.Height / 2 - logoSize / 2, logoSize, logoSize));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return File(qrCodeBytes, "image/png");
    }
}
```

}

Image link is correct

This is just an example of my logo. there is a mistake please ignore.

My code works fine but it doesn't show the logo in the QR code

Comment: Why do you make screenshots from text which you can easily copy‘paste here? Please edit this question and post the code as text.

Comment: Did you add the [QRCoder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QRCoder/) package to your project?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We have certain guidelines on questions here and in is current form, your question doesn't meet up to them. Please look at the [help], especially [ask]. For a quick preview of the site, take the [tour]. Here you at least need a [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm newbie and I'll go into more detail on how to ask

Comment: Are you able to access the logo.jpg in your code?

Comment: If you can't get it working to add a logo to a QR code, take a look at [this forum post](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t18103-), which uses LEADTOOLS Imaging SDK to add an animated logo and save it as animated GIF. (Disclosure: I work for the SDK's vendor). Of course, you can create static image without animation if that's what you need. You can find a free evaluation of the SDK [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).